# windows forms scaling issue on high dpi display

Tags: winforms, dpi

I am having an issue with auto scaling while trying to create a Windows forms app.  I'm currently running on a Dell laptop with a 3840 x 2160 display (4K).  I'm trying to add an image to a picture box, and if I leave the picture at its native size (which is quite small on my display) it appears at a correct autosized scale when I go to run the app.  The issue with this is at the native picture's size it is very difficult to lay out all the other items I want to add to the app. If I increase the size of the picture to something that is usable it increase the size of the image to something large enough it doesn't fit on my screen.  I know this is likely due to the auto scaling Windows 10 does, but I wanted to see if anyone else might have a work around for this?  I've tried to see if there is a way to zoom in the display in the designer window, but I haven't found anything.  I have also noticed the size of the windows forms app itself changes depending on where I have items placed on it.

Comment: So I guess I figured out a sort of work around...  I just made the entire form on my desktop PC that has a standard 1920x1080 monitor, and then transferred the project to my laptop.  It is interesting though, the size of the form looks to be scaled up to fit my monitor, but the images are at their original size.  Maybe that's how I need to work with thing from now on?  I can try to add a screenshot of what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I completely understand what you're asking, but I would assume it could have something to do with the pixel units of your elements. Here's an excellent [explanation of point-based vs pixel-based sizing](https://medium.com/@pnowelldesign/pixel-density-demystified-a4db63ba2922#.l3onofjj8)

Comment: Right now if I try to keep the image I'm using at it's native resolution (600x200, so it appears correctly when I run the app) my entire form is far too small to work with (there just isn't any room to add new items to the form).  If I increase the size of the image to one that is actually workable (1800x600) the image is larger than my screen when I go to run it due to the autoscaling Windows does for high DPI displays.  I need a way to be able to zoom in the designer view.

Comment: I can increase the entire size of the form, and keep the image the original size (600x200), but then when I run it everything is spaced out too far and generally looks bad.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments.  The size limit was way too small to try and explain everything.